Why won't this switch work in my house?
I'm in Canada in a three bedroom house built in 1958. The wiring upstairs was all done with just two conductor wire: hot and neutral. (A lot of the wiring in the basement is 3-conductor as a result of the contractor who built the rec room in the 1970s.)
I have a hallway upstairs linking the three bedrooms and the bathroom and it has only a single switch for its light and that's in the middle of the hallway. Finding that switch in the dark is something of a challenge so I'd like to get some kind of night light in the hallway but there are absolutely no outlets anywhere in the hallway. (I was thinking of replacing the current light with something that has a motion detector but we have a cat and I assume she would have the light on and off constantly as she walks up and down that hallway regularly at night.)
The other day, I was looking for a solution and found a switch that combines a light switch and a night light. The night light comes on automatically in low light conditions so it seemed perfect. I bought the light but encountered a problem when I went to install it.
This new switch/nightlight has FOUR connectors on it, labelled hot, neutral, ground, and load. As I've said, we don't have ground wires upstairs so I connected my hot wire to the hot terminal, my neutral wire to the neutral terminal, and then turned the breaker on to see what would happen. The night light works as intended - I can test it by tapping it in daylight and it lights for a few seconds before turning off - but the light in the ceiling of the hallway does NOT light up in either position.
Is there any way to make this switch work in my hallway? I'm assuming the problem is that the "load" terminal doesn't have a wire on it but I have no idea what, if anything, I can do about that since I don't have any other wires in that box.
In response to comments:
The switch depicted in the link is brand new. I assume it's working though I suppose it could be defective.
I'm not sure what you mean by "switch junction box". The only box I opened was the one containing the existing switch which is a simple on/off toggle. There are only two wires in that box, a black one and a white one. The black wire was connected to one screw terminal of the toggle switch and the white wire was connected to the other screw terminal of the toggle switch. Virtually none of the outlets and switches upstairs have more than two wires coming into them. I found this out many years ago when I first bought something with a three-prong plug: all the outlets had two prong receptacles. I got around this initially with cheaters but they were soon banned so I went into each receptacle and replaces each two-prong receptacle with a three-prong receptacle, leaving the ground terminal unconnected.
Getting into the attic would be a big chore. There is an access through one of the closets but I'd have to unpack a lot of stuff to get up there. I'm not sure what metal conduit or NB cable are; I'd need to see pictures and even then I suppose it's pointless to dig them up because I'm reluctant to climb around in the attic; there is no floor there, just joists.
This house is not drywall, the walls are plaster. I'm really not keen on cutting a hole in the wall to install a receptacle. I just found a much simpler solution: a battery-powered night light that uses a motion detector. It doesn't look like the motion detector has adjustable sensitivity but it seems to me that if I place it so that is not shining directly into a bedroom, it doesn't matter if the cat triggers it: it will only come on for a minute, then shut off. I won't see it so it won't wake me up.

Also quite possible you have no neutral wire either.  If just a single cable with black and white wire, then the white is/supposed to be always hot(and marked with black tape), and the black is your switched hot/load.  Ground is just a safety for you, and does not matter to the circuit working if there or not.

@crip659, I've some old dimmer switches that used the ground as if neutral, since the switch had two leads (in series with lamp and line) but needed a neutral. Wonder if that meet code now?

A picture would help -- how many wires go through the switch junction box? Are there both line and neutral going in, and line and neutral going out?

@DrMoishePippik  I do not think that ever was in code.  It is an old hack to bypass a broken/missing neutral.  Neutral is an insulated conductor to pass current.  Ground is usually bare and is not made to carry current, except for a few seconds.

Do you have attic access on the second floor?  do you have metal conduit or NB cable?

It worked before but now it does not work ?

Ignore ground for the moment. Can't ignore it on new circuits, and some switches/devices actually require ground. But I doubt that is the issue here.
IMPORTANT
In response to an update:

I went into each receptacle and replaces each two-prong receptacle with a three-prong receptacle, leaving the ground terminal unconnected.

DON'T DO THAT!
The reason the "cheaters" are banned is because if the box isn't actually grounded or if the cheater ground tab doesn't securely contact the box via a metal screw, you think you have ground and you don't, which is far worse than not having a ground pin at all!
There are three ways to properly install a three-prong receptacles:

Properly grounded via a ground wire. You don't appear to have that option without rewiring in some way.
Properly grounded via metal boxes to metal conduit or to a ground wire on the outside of the box (i.e., inside the wall). There is a small possibility you actually have that. I found that several two-prong receptacles without ground wires inside the box actually had ground wires outside the box. That is not standard practice, but if the ground wire is securely fastened then it does work, though ideally you want to move the wire to be inside the box. You might have that situation. The easy way to tell is to use a "magic 8-ball tester", such as this Klein from Amazon:


If it shows a good result ("CORRECT" on this model) with either a three-prong receptacle or a two-prong receptacle with a "cheater" then you have a grounded box and your three-prong receptacle is OK or if you still have a two-prong receptacle you can replace with a "self-grounding" three-prong receptacle and you're all set.

GFCI protection in lieu of a ground wire. This can be done with a GFCI/breaker or a GFCI/receptacle. It can extend to multiple load-side protected receptacles. Each protected receptacle requires a sticker to indicate that their is no actual ground and any receptacle (except a GFCI/receptacle device) needs to have a sticker to indicate that it is GFCI-protected.

What you described might turn out to match the second possibility. Test the receptacles and find out. If they are not properly grounded then you must either install GFCI to provide protection or revert to two-prong receptacles. You can't have three-prong receptacles that are not protected via either ground or GFCI.

A simple switch only requires hot (also called line) and switched hot (also called load). Which means that (again, ignoring ground) a typical single switch in a box will either have:

Two cables with black and white. One black is hot, the other black is switched hot, and both hots connect to the switch. The whites are neutral and connect together.
One cable with black and white. The white should be hot and the black switched hot, though other than avoiding confusion (which is important for safety) it makes no electrical difference which is which. Repeat after me: Neutral is always white, white is not always neutral. This is one of those cases where white is not neutral.

In ye olden times, only timers typically needed neutral for a switch. Which meant that the second way of wiring could save some wire if things were planned accordingly. But now smart switches of various types, as well as lighted switches, timers, motion sensors and many other things, require neutral. And you don't have neutral in that switch box.
More generally, smart switches/etc. need to get power somehow. That can be:

Neutral - easiest, if it is already in the box
Ground - easy in most houses, but limited by code to very low power
Battery - OK for a lot of electronic timers and similar things, but not very good for lighting, even low-power night lights
Leak power through the circuit - not generally a good idea with LEDs

Which means that more and more people could really use neutral in every switch box. Code has changed to now require neutral in most switch boxes. But older wiring does not have to be changed.
As for a solution here, forget about this switch. It won't work without rewiring your lighting circuit.
In most homes, there are receptacles on each wall of the room. Assuming you have typical (for US/Canada 1950s homes) drywall on stud construction:

Find a receptacle on the other side of one of the hallway walls
Cut a hole for a receptacle on the hallway side
Install a nice metal box and receptacle
Run a cable from the old receptacle to the new receptacle
Plug in your night light in the new hallway receptacle


the OP could also repair the switch and correctly wire it

@Traveler The switch is perfectly fine. The problem is that OP has an old-style switch loop with no neutral. The switch requires neutral.

how come it worked with old switch

@Traveler The old switch was a simple toggle switch. The new switch has a light in it.

The switch has a hot and a switched-hot wire, no neutral.
The reason the nighlight is lighting is that it is permanently in series with the main lamp, and that allows enough current to flow to light the (probably LED) nightlight, but not the main (probably incandescent) lamp. As you have correctly deduced, the lamp is not connected to the "load" terminal, so the switch doesn't do anything.
(I'd bet money on the hot wire on the lamp being live permanently, when the lamp is disconnected.)
If you move the "neutral" (actually the switched hot) to the load terminal, then the switch should function, but the nighlight will not.
There's no easy (read safe) way to make this work, without running hot & neutral to your switch.
Edit:
I've just seen your comment about replacing the two-prong sockets with three-prong ones with no ground.
I strongly urge you to not engage in any more electrical work, as you are clearly out of your depth if you thought this was a sensible thing to do; You may well end up killing someone - quite possibly yourself.
